# Index of last checked change checkbox from list of them

Tags: c#, winforms

How to get the index of last checkbox where checked change from list of them? If someone asks, no, I can't use CheckedListBox control for this project.

I have

`List<CheckBox> checkboxes = new List<CheckBox>();`

and then I adding some checkboxes to this list

What I want to do is to get the index of checkbox which recently checked state changed

so...
every checkbox from this list have this same handler for the `CheckedChanged` event

and then in this void I want to get index of this checkbox which trigger this event for example for this code

```
public void checked_change(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = // here i want this index
            if (checkboxes[x].Checked==true)
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `object sender` argument to the event-handler contains the 'recently changed' `CheckBox`.

You would need to cast the `object` back to the `CheckBox` type and find it's index in the list using `List.IndexOf`.

```
int x = checkboxes.IndexOf((CheckBox)sender);
```

Make sure you only hook `CheckBox`es onto the event-handler or perform a safe conversion